# Django url that captures yyyy-mm-dd date

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

How do you capture a url that contains yyyy-mm-dd in Django. So like www.mydomain.com/2011-02-12. I tried:

```
url(r'^(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

But, the server says page not found.

Answer (score 19):

In Django 3.0.5 I did this using the following urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from datetime import datetime
from . import views

class DateConverter:
    regex = '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value

register_converter(DateConverter, 'yyyy')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('date/<yyyy:date>/', views.date, name='date'),
]
```

Comment: Great, in contrast to the accepted answer, this worked for Django 3.1

Comment: can't understand why this isn't part of Django itself... There is even an UUIDConverter...

Answer (score 8):

You should have a group name in the url pattern:

```
url(r'^(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', views.index, name='index'),
#          ^^^^
```

Also pay attention to the trailing slash in the url: `www.mydomain.com/2011-02-12/`. If you don't want a slash in the url, you can remove it from the pattern.

---

And your view function would then take the name of the group as one of its parameters

```
def index(request, date):
    ...
```

You should see the [docs on Django url named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#named-groups)

Comment: While all of this is true, none of it would cause the "not found" error reported in the question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The trailing slash would. The pattern in the question includes the trailing slash, while the URL does not.

Comment: does my regex actually captures yyyy-mm-dd?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
url(r'^(?P<date>[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{2})/$', views.index, name='index'),
```