# Django DayArchiveview is not detected in urls.py

Tags: python, django

I created several date-based views in Django, and while views for year and month function as expected, the view to display days is not detected. For instance, if I try to get http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021/, or http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021/01 the views will be displayed, http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021/01/07 will fail. I understand that the problem must be with urls.py configuration, but I just cannot find it in documentation. I also tried passing day_format='%d' to as_view method, without any results.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from blog import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    # Example: /blog/
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # Example: /blog/post/ (same as /blog/)
    path('post/', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),

    # Example: /blog/post/django-example/
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/
    path('archive/', views.PostArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/2019/
    path('archive/<int:year>/', views.PostYearArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_year_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/2019/nov/
    path('archive/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.PostMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'), name='post_month_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/2019/nov/10/
    path('archive/<int:year>/<str:month>/<int:day>/', views.PostDayArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_day_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/today/
    path('archive/today/', views.PostTodayArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_today_archive'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, ArchiveIndexView, YearArchiveView, MonthArchiveView, \
    DayArchiveView, TodayArchiveView

from blog.models import Post


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_all.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostArchiveView(ArchiveIndexView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'


class PostYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
    make_object_list = True


class PostMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'


class PostDayArchiveView(DayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'


class PostTodayArchiveView(TodayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
```

**post_archive_day.html**

```
<h1>Post Archives for {{ day|date:"N d, Y" }}</h1>

<div>
    <ul>
        {% for post in object_list %}
        <li>
            {{ post.modify_dt|date:"Y-m-d" }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><strong>{{ post.title }}</strong></a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**errors**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL pattern is matching correctly, specifically `'archive/<int:year>/<str:month>/<int:day>/'` will be matched for URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021/01/07.

The error message indicates an invalid date string. It expects that the month field, specified as `%b`, be an abbreviated month *name*. So your URL should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021/jan/07 as per the comment above your URL pattern in `urls.py`.

**Update**

You can change the expected month format to a zero padded month number by setting `month_format` in your `PostDayArchiveView`.

```
class PostDayArchiveView(DayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
    month_format = '%m'
```

Now you can use the URL pattern `'archive/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/'` to accept your desired URL format.

Comment: i replace archive/<int:year>/<str:month>/<int:day>/ to archive/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/

but its not working as same error again

Comment: The month _must_ be an abbreviated month name. This is hard-coded in the `DayArchiveView` generic view. Changing your URL pattern to match an integer is not going to change that.

Comment: then where and what should i fix?

Comment: You don't need to fix anything if you can accept that months use the abbreviated month name format. That's what the generic date views accept, and I don't think that they can (easily) be overridden.

Comment: but when i use %m and replace <str:~> to <int:~>, the error remains yet

Comment: Where are you specifying `%m` and why?

Comment: @박종준: I have updated my answer which shows how to override the month format. It's actually very easy! Sorry, it took me a while to dig around in the internals of the generic date view code.

Comment: i know but how about day? the day of error is again "Invalid date string “2021__1__7” given format “%Y__%b__%d” "

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the date in this way ->`http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021-01-07` instead of this -> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021/01/07`. This will be a more easy way to handle things what you want

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from datetime import datetime
from . import views

class DateConverter:
    regex = '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')

    def to_url(self, value):
       return value

register_converter(DateConverter, 'yyyy')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('date/<yyyy:date>/', views.date, name='date'),
]
```

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212865/django-url-that-captures-yyyy-mm-dd-date) question

Comment: OP is using generic date views which expect dates in a specific format.