# How to pass a parameter date to url dispatcher but as named parameter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've been reading lots of tutorials and stackoverflow questions, but I haven't found how to do this. I need to pass a parameter of type Date in a GET call on the URL.
I know it sounds easy, but I'm new to Django and what I have found is mostly something like this:

[Django url that captures yyyy-mm-dd date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212865/django-url-that-captures-yyyy-mm-dd-date)

All those answers solve the issue if I want to have an URL like

```
http:www.myweb.com/2021/09/02
```

That is great if I want to write an url for a blog or website, but I'm doing it for an endpoint, and in my case, I need something like this

```
/some-action-endpoint/?created_at_gte=2020-01-01
```

So, I need to capture a parameter (hopefully named created_at_gte) with the value 2020-02-01 (It will awesome if I could capture that immediately as a Date object, but I'm fine with a string)

So, my questions are:
1.- It will be enough to create a group like this

```
url(r'^my-endpoint/(?P<created_at_gte>[(\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{4})]{4})/$', views.my_view),
```

Note_: by the way, the previous one is not working, if someone knows why it'll greatly appreciate it.

2.-The endpoint needs two parameters: created_at_gte and created_at_lte. How can I handle this? Do I need to add two url's to the url pattern?

I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7. Cannot use other versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query parameters aren't part of the URL matching behavior, so unfortunately your requirement to handle them as query parameters instead of URL path elements means you have to do more on your own rather than relying on pattern matching to reject bad requests.

You can do what you want as long as your base URL pattern (`^my-endpoint/` in your example) is unambiguous and you're willing to handle the possibility that the parameters may not be set or may be set to something that doesn't parse as a date in your view, but you won't get the regexp-derived guarantees or the ability to bind them to view function parameters.

Instead, you'll have to extract them from the `request.GET` `QueryDict` object. That would look something like this:

In your url patterns:

```
url(r'^my-endpoint/$', views.my_view),
```

And then in your views:

```
def my_view(request):
    created_at_start = request.GET.get("created_at_gte")
    created_at_end = request.GET.get("created_at_lte")
    # you now have no guarantees about these values except that if not None they'll be strings
    # remember to do something appropriate for None, empty strings, strings that aren't dates, strings where end is before the start, etc
```

Comment: @JohnSmith - if my answer resolved your question, you may wish to mark it as accepted. This shows other users that the issue is resolved. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work