# how to show date in url django

Tags: python, django, datetime

im trying to return objects based on date (yyyy-mm-dd) but it returns this :

> Reverse for 'daily_detail' with arguments '(datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 19, 0, 0),)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['my/url/for/(?P\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$']

this is my views.py

```
#my lists
def daily_list(request):
    lists = MyModel.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('date')).values('day').order_by('-day')

#this is my day detail 
def daily_report(request,day):
    daily_report = MyModel.objects.annotate(day=TruncDay('date')).filter(day=day).order_by('-pk')
context = {
    'daily_report':daily_report
}
```

and this is my urls.py

```
path('list/daily',daily_list,name='daily_list'),
path('list/daily/<str:day>',daily_report,name='daily_report'),
```

but it returns the above error

and this is my template

```html
{% for i in lists %}
<!--other informations -->
<td class="p-2 text-xs border border-purple-900 md:text-base textpurple">
                    <a href="{% url 'myAppUrl:daily_report' i.day %}"><button><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></button></a> 
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

thank you for your suggestions ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django url that captures yyyy-mm-dd date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41212865/django-url-that-captures-yyyy-mm-dd-date)

Comment: @ThePyGuy no , still shows the same error

Comment: i change to `path('list/daily/<yyyy:day>',daily_report,name='daily_report')` with adding the other code into my urls.py

Comment: but not work , i think i have to change the `day` from template , to this `{% url 'myAppUrl:daily_report'  i.day | date:'d-m-Y'}`

Comment: Also, the error clearly mentions `(datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 19, 0, 0),)` its a datetime object, instead it should have been string value

Comment: @ThePyGuy but it wont let you to do that

Comment: `{% url 'myAppUrl:daily_report'  i.day %}` it return `2021, 8, 19, 0, 0` two last 0 should be removed

Comment: @ThePyGuy have you any idea please

Comment: it seems like the return type of TruncDay is date time object ?